# Prove (by calculating the integral) that $\int_C \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r} =0$ for $\vec{F}=\langle x,y,z\rangle$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

In the following $C$ is a curve on a sphere of radius $a$ of center $(0,0,0)$.

I get the geometric interpretation that since $\vec{F}=\langle x,y,z \rangle$ is perpendicular to the tangent:

$$\int_C \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}= \int_C \vec{F} \cdot \hat{T} ds=0$$

However, I couldn't prove it by doing the integral. $$\int_C xdx +ydy +zdz$$

I tried parametrizing the sphere into polar coordinates but then I'll have more than 1 variable and won't be able to convert $dx, dy, dz$ into one $ A(t)dt$

Comment: $C$ cannot be a surface. What is it?

Comment: Parametrize the sphere in terms of the standard polar and azimuthal angles $\phi$ and $\theta$, and then take any curve $C$ on the sphere by parametrizing $\phi$ and $\theta$ in terms of a single parameter of the curve. You will end up with $\vec r (\theta(s),\phi(s))$ which you can then differentiate with respect to $s$ using chain rule and carry out the integral.

Comment: Use `\langle` and `\rangle` for angle brackets, not `<` and `>`.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment. Use that $\vec{F}$ is curl free and therefore a gradient
of a function. The line integral depends only on the end points of the curve
so you can choose a straight line instead.

> $$\vec{F}=\nabla f(x,y,z)=\nabla\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}2$$$$\vec{r}(t)=\pmatrix{x_0+t(x_1-x_0)\\y_0+t(y_1-y_0)\\z_0+t(z_1-z_0)}$$$$\frac{d}{dt}\vec{r}(t)=\pmatrix{x_1-x_0\\y_1-y_0\\z_1-z_0}$$gives$$\int_C\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}=f(x_1,y_1,z_1)-f(x_0,y_0,z_0)\,.$$Since $f$ is constant on the sphere of any radius this is zero.